# Debian - How to get notified when packages for "dist-upgrade" are available?

Tags: debian, cron, apt-get

I automated `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` by using the package `unattended-upgrades` together with `anacron`.
It makes sense that `unattended-upgrades` does not execute `apt-get dist-upgrade`, since there is the risk of breaking things.

However I at least would like to know that there are packages available for dist-upgrade(e.g. mail to root). I dont want to check that by hand again and again.

How can I do this ?

Comment: I am not very experienced with linux, but have always wondered this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your system is always automatically updated with `apt-get upgrade` this script run by a cronjob could do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Optional run this command first if not using automatic upgrades
# sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y

pkglist=$(apt-get -su --assume-no dist-upgrade)
pending=$(echo "$pkglist" | grep -oE "[0-9]+ upgraded, [0-9]+ newly installed, [0-9]+ to remove and [0-9]+ not upgraded\.")
upgraded=$(echo "$pending" | grep -oE "[0-9]+ upgraded" | cut -d' ' -f1)
installed=$(echo "$pending" | grep -oE "[0-9]+ newly installed" | cut -d' ' -f1)
removed=$(echo "$pending" | grep -oE "[0-9]+ to remove" | cut -d' ' -f1)
count=$(( $upgraded + $installed + $removed ))
if [ "$count" -ne "0" ]; then
  echo "$count pending packages to upgrade/install/remove, sending email"
  echo "$pkglist" | mail -s "dist-upgrade: $count pending packages" email@example.com
fi
```

The script checks for pending packages with the following command

```
apt-get -su --assume-no dist-upgrade
```

Options:

- **-s**, performs a simulation
- **-u**, print a list of upgraded packages
- **-assume-no**, automatic "no" to all prompts

If there are any pending packages to be upgraded, newly installed or to remove, the script sends an email to `email@example.com` with the list of packages and prints out a message.

> Possible alternative: **apticron**
>
> This package will send daily emails if there are any pending packages.
>   It should also solve your problem, as it also informs about packages that have been kept back.